# @Url.Action getting ?Length=2 appended

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this at the top of each of several translations of the "Terms of Use" page:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms")">English</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", "de")">Deutsch</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", "fr")">Français</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", "it")">Italiano</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", "nl")">Nederlands</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", "hu")">Maygar</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", "es")">Español</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", "zh")">简体中文</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", "pt-pt")">European Português</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", "pt")">Português</a></li>
```

This is the action that should handle the clicks:

```
public class TermsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case "de":
                return View("de");
            case "fr":
                return View("fr");
            case "it":
                return View("it");
            case "nl":
                return View("nl");
            case "hu":
                return View("hu");
            case "es":
                return View("es");
            case "zh":
                return View("zh");
            case "pt":
                return View("pt");
            case "pt-pt":
                return View("pt-pt");
            default:
                return View();
        }
    }
```

and these are my routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Terms",
        "{controller}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Terms", action = "Index" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "ThankYou",
        "{controller}/{action}/{email}/{id}"
        );
}
```

From the main (i.e., English) Terms page, the first (i.e., English) link looks correct:

```
http://localhost:65391/Terms/
```

Why do the other (i.e., foreign) generated URLs look like this?

```
http://localhost:65391/Terms/?Length=2
```

Also, oddly, if I manually type in

```
http://localhost:65391/Terms/de
```

for example, and go to the Terms page in German, then the first hyperlink (i.e., back to the English Terms page) looks like this:

```
http://localhost:65391/Terms/de
```

Go here to see the actual site:

http://inrix.com/traffic/terms

Comment: Using only one tag makes your question hard to discover. You should tag it at least additional with the MVC vesion tag. like asp.net-mvc-3 or asp.net-mvc-4 etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of the `Url.Action` which treats the third argument as the **routeValues** object.

From the MSDN:

> routeValues
>   Type: System.Object
>   An object that contains the parameters
>   for a route. The parameters are retrieved through reflection by
>   examining the properties of the object. The object is typically
>   created by using object initializer syntax.

So you have passed strings `"de", "fr"` as the third argument so MVC have taken its properties and made key value pairs: that is where the `Length=2` is coming, because the `string` class has one property `Length` and the value is 2 for your strings.

You can fix this easily with passing an anonymous object wrapping your strings:

```cs
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms" new { id = "" })">English</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", new { id = "de" })">Deutsch</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Terms", new { id = "fr" })">Français</a></li>
...
```

Notes:

- your annonymous object property name `id` should match your route segment name `id` and controller parameter name `id`
- you need to expicilty pass `new { id = "" }` in the default case otherwise MVC will use the already given route values. This is what you have seen in the `http://localhost:65391/Terms/de` case. So the English link became `http://localhost:65391/Terms/de` because MVC already found the `id` value in the URL which was `de` and automatically reused it.
- <sub>Last Note the correct spelling is Magyar and not Maygar</sub>

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! (Thanks for the heads up on the spelling error, too!)