# Trouble with routing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I've got an ASP.NET MVC site under a Classic ASP site. The MVC site is:

http://www.inrix.com/traffic

The routes

http://www.inrix.com/traffic
http://www.inrix.com/traffic/home
http://www.inrix.com/traffic/features

work fine. However, the route:

http://www.inrix.com/traffic/support

does not. Click it to see what I'm getting. If I include the action:

http://www.inrix.com/traffic/support/index

it works.

When I run this at home by pressing F5 in VS, it works fine with just http://www.inrix.com/traffic/support (i.e., no action specified). Here are my routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Terms",
        "{controller}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Terms", action = "Index" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "ThankYou",
        "{controller}/{action}/{email}/{id}"
        );
}
```

www.inrix.com/traffic maps to HomeController (Index action).

I want www.inrix.com/traffic/support to map to SupportController, Index action.

What's going on with the "support" route?

**Additional Code:**

Controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace InrixTraffic.Controllers
{
    public class SupportController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Support</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

New route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Support",
        "traffic/support",
        new { controller = "Support", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@EDIT: 
I think you have a file path (folder probably) with that same url. I mean, a folder named "support".
In order to override file path with route path you need to add:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Comment: You're correct about F5 running debug at localhost.

See the end of the post for clarification of your questions.

Comment: @birdus, please check my updated answer and delete previous comments for simplicity on the discussion. Hope that works.

Comment: That's it! As it turns out, I didn't really need that directory, so I just deleted it and that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Traffic controller with an Index action? If so I think you need to set-up a route like whats shown below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Terms",
    "traffic/support",
    new { controller = "Traffic", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Place this route above your Terms route in your RegisterRoutes method.

**EDIT**

I would setup my routes like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Support",
        "traffic/support",
        new { controller = "Support", action = "Index" }
    );

    // don't know why you need the id at the end
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Terms",
        "terms",
        new { controller = "Terms", action = "Index" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    // why does this route not have any defaults defined?
    routes.MapRoute(
        "ThankYou",
        "{controller}/{action}/{email}/{id}"
        );
}
```

Comment: Traffic actually goes to HomeController. SupportController.Index is where I want this URL to go. I clarified that at the bottom of the question.

Comment: So you want to add this route instead `routes.MapRoute(
    "Terms",
    "traffic/support",
    new { controller = "Support", action = "Index" }
    );`

Comment: The reason your `traffic/support` route is failing to match is because your Default route will look for a TrafficController with a 'Support' Action. You need to put the above route before the Default route in your RegisterRoutes method.

Comment: Okay. I added that new route, then uploaded the global.asax and the newly compiled dll for the site into the bin folder. The behavior still appears to be the same, however. What am I missing? (see the original question for more code examples) By the way, the new route is the first route in the route table.

Comment: Try using Phil Haacks Route Debugger available here. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx This will show you which routes are being matched.

Comment: Neat tool! So, if you hit the home page of the MVC app (http://www.inrix.com/traffic), you get the route info. However, if you hit the problem page (http://www.inrix.com/traffic/support), it's not doing anything. That's gotta tell us something—I just don't know what!

Comment: Thanks for your help with the basics on routing. The Id for Terms is because there can be a number of languages and I'm passing in something like "de" for the language (de = German). That's something else I'm having a problem with and haven't gotten an answer for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688789/url-action-getting-length-2-appended

Comment: Looks like I don't even need the Support route. I removed it and the route works just fine. I like simpler. Looks like that uses the Default route.